# Conexion entre postman y ASP.NET

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, postman

Hola estoy tratando de enviar datos de postman a ASP.NET pero a la hora de ver los datos enviados no llega ninguno por alguna razon pero si se llama al metodo, pues usando el depurador veo que se llama la  funcion pero con valores nulos como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Codigo de que recibe la peticion:

```
       [HttpPost]
       public void Eliminar([FromRoute] Chofere chofer)
        {/*Chofere chofer*/
            Console.WriteLine("");
            

            var lista2 = new List<VehiclePerson>();

            con.Open();
            OracleCommand getEmps2 = con.CreateCommand();
            getEmps2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM VEHICLE_PERSON  WHERE CREDENT_NUMBER = '" + chofer.Tag+"'";
            getEmps2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataReader empDR2 = getEmps2.ExecuteReader();
            if (empDR2.HasRows)
            {
                while (empDR2.Read())
                {
                    lista2.Add(new VehiclePerson()
                    {
                        EMP_NUMBER = empDR2["EMP_NUMBER"].ToString(),
                        FIRSTNAME = empDR2["FIRSTNAME"].ToString(),
                        LASTNAME = empDR2["LASTNAME"].ToString(),
                        COSTCENTER = empDR2["COSTCENTER"].ToString(),
                        DEPARTMENT = empDR2["DEPARTMENT"].ToString(),
                        CREDENT_NUMBER = empDR2["CREDENT_NUMBER"].ToString(),
                        FROM_DATE = empDR2["FROM_DATE"].ToString(),
                        TO_DATE = empDR2["TO_DATE"].ToString(),
                        RIGHTS1 = empDR2["RIGHTS1"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
            con.Close();
       }
```

Este codigo es la clase de Chofere

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace APITDCON.Models.TANKFARM;

public partial class Chofere
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? Nombre { get; set; }

    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    public string? SecondLastName { get; set; }

    public string? Telefono { get; set; }

    public int? IdCliente { get; set; }

    public int? IdIdioma { get; set; }

    public string? Gerente { get; set; }

    public string? Departamento { get; set; }

    public string? CentroCostos { get; set; }

    public string? Perfil { get; set; }

    public string? Correo { get; set; }

    public string? Tag { get; set; }

    public string? Status { get; set; }

    public string? NameComplete { get; set; }

    public string? G_FROM_DATE { get; set; }

    public string? G_TO_DATE { get; set; }

    public string? G_RIGHTS { get; set; }

    public string? G_DESCRIPTIONSTATUS { get; set; }
}
```

Este es el valor enviado por postman en formato json:

```
{
    "Id": 0,
    "Nombre": "OSCAR ISAAC",
    "LastName": null,
    "SecondLastName": null,
    "Telefono": null,
    "IdCliente": 0,
    "IdIdioma": 0,
    "Gerente": null,
    "Departamento": null,
    "CentroCostos": null,
    "Perfil": null,
    "Correo": null,
    "Tag": "35510441092",
    "Status": null,
    "NameComplete": null,
    "G_FROM_DATE": null,
    "G_TO_DATE": null,
    "G_RIGHTS": null,
    "G_DESCRIPTIONSTATUS": null
}
```

Esta es la configuracion de Postman:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta lo que envio a postman y la configuracion de envio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si necesitan mas informacion pregunten para responder.

Comment: Hola Leonardo, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código como texto, gracias.

Comment: Y si cambias `[FromRoute]` por `[FromBody]` ???

Comment: Hola Yussef cambie FromRoute por FromBody y funciono correctamente gracias